# How to understand C++ variable scoping rules?

Tags: c++, class, scope, segmentation-fault, extern

I've recently returned to C++ from scripting languages like PHP and LSL and some of its scoping rules are confusing me.

Say I have a Viewer.h like so:

```
class Viewer {

    public:

        Viewer();
        ~Viewer();

        void    ping();
        void    setBgColour(int r, int g, int b, int a);

        float   bg_r;
        float   bg_g;
        float   bg_b;
        float   bg_a;
};
```

and a Viewer.C like so:

```
#include "Globals.h"
#include "Viewer.h"

Viewer::Viewer() {}
Viewer::~Viewer() {}

void Viewer::ping() {

    cout << "Viewer::ping() " << endl;
}

void Viewer::setBgColour(int r, int g, int b, int a) {

    bg_r = r/255.0;
    bg_g = g/255.0;
    bg_b = b/255.0;
    bg_a = a/255.0;
}
```

I've declared an instance of my viewer class in Global.{h|C} as 'extern' in order to be able to access the global viewer instance from other files.

Now consider this, when I call the global viewer instance methods in for example UI.C:

```
viewer->ping();
viewer->setBgColour(123, 45, 56, 255);
```

the viewer->ping() works fine, but viewer->setBgColour() gives me a segmentation fault when it tries to access the instance variables bg_r, bg_g, bg_b and bg_a.

My understanding is that I'm not accessing the right viewer instance.

viewer->ping() doesn't care, as it will just echo text to cout regardless of the instance it's actually called from. But setBgColour() needs access to the correct memory locations, thus it segfaults when it can't find them.

This confuses me as I was/am under the impression that declaring my viewer instance as 'extern' would 'just work'. Silly me. I have tried declaring the variables as 'static' but that just confused me more.

Comment: Have you actually allocated a `Viewer`, or do you just have an uninitialised pointer? If all you have is `Viewer* viewer;` then you have the latter.

Comment: You should show the line of code where you create the viewer! I suspect @JonathanPotter is right.

Comment: Is the value of `viewer` equal to `nullptr`? If `viewer` is a global then you should check it has been constructed before you use it.

Comment: Iindeed the viewer was called and initialised. Thanks for pointing out that I should have mentioned this in my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no more done to `viewer` in code before posted lines, then you have uninitialized pointer `Viewer* viewer`. Dereferencing such pointer causes segmentation fault. If you want to fix it, you should assign address of created object to the pointer.

Possibly:

(at the beginning of `main`)

```
viewer = new Viewer();

// some code here

delete viewer;
```

Or assign address of existing global variable to it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a global instance, consider using a singleton. There's really no need to allocate your viewer on the heap.

e.g.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Viewer 
{
    float   bg_r;
    float   bg_g;
    float   bg_b;
    float   bg_a;

    Viewer(Viewer const&) = delete;
    Viewer& operator=(Viewer const&) = delete;

    public:

    Viewer()
        : bg_r(0.0), bg_g(0.0), bg_b(0.0), bg_a(0.0)
    {}
    void    ping();
    void    setBgColour(int r, int g, int b, int a);      
};

void Viewer::ping() 
{
    cout << "Viewer::ping()\n";
}

void Viewer::setBgColour(int r, int g, int b, int a) 
{
    bg_r = r/255.0;
    bg_g = g/255.0;
    bg_b = b/255.0;
    bg_a = a/255.0;
}

Viewer& GetViewer()
{
    static Viewer v;
    return v;
}

int main()
{
    GetViewer().ping();
    GetViewer().setBgColour(1,2,3,4);
}
```

Comment: A singleton isn't a bad idea, but this implementation still allows you create another instance like this: `Viewer im_a_copy = Viewer::GetViewer();`. The fix is to either delete the copy constructor or mark it as private.

Comment: Good point fixed. thank you

Comment: Thanks Paul, for this comment. I'd been deliberating wether using singletons was the way to go, but then got all bumfuzzled by the 'singletons are evil' debate and used globals instead. Your comment and code snippet also made me go back and revisit the ideas of stack and heap and memory allocation in C/C++ in general - so for its 'meta' effect I'd like to select your answer as the preferred one to my question.